# Securing ADFS with External Authentication and Smart Cards

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, adfs3.0, multi-factor-authentication

We have developed an External Authentication dll (using C# .NET) for Windows Server 2012 R2 ADFS. You can select this MFA adapter and after your credentials have been validated (first authentication factor), you are presented with a form to input an OTP (second factor of authentication).

So far so good, now we want to include support for Smart Cards (PIN validation) for our External authentication adapter in the ADFS. How can we achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by a smartcard here? Typically these mean client TLS with a cert released by a PIN. We don't support this pattern in the external additional authenticator. However, if the cert is trusted in AD, you can use user certificate authentication that in box in ADFS. We have many customers to use this. This type of mapping in AD can be via UPN mapping or via altSecID.

Comment: So, if the cert is trusted in the AD, Will I have to ask the user for a certificate (during the login process), and then, do a certificate authentication using the external authentication adapter? Is there's any chance we can use StackOverflow chat to clarify some doubts about this?

Comment: So, if the cert is mapped to AD, you don't have to do this in the second factor process, we do this automatically. You would only use your adapter for OTP.